# I want to compare the price of stock with stoploss and alert me by email

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to compare my list of stocks price with my set Stoploss which is stored and once the condition trigger alert by email. Below is my code

```
function emailAlert()
{
  var stock1nameRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist").getRange("A5");
  var stock1name = stock1nameRange.getValues();
  var stock1cmpRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist").getRange("B5");
  var stock1cmp = stock1cmpRange.getValues();
  var stock1s1Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist").getRange("AK5");
  var s1 = stock1s1Range.getValues();
  var stock1s2Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchlist").getRange("AL5");
  var s2 = stock1s2Range.getValues();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(stock1cmp<s1)
  {
    if(stock1cmp<s2)
    {
      ui.alert( stock1name + stock1cmp +  'is less than' +s2 );
      var message = stock1name + stock1cmp +  'is less than' +s2 ; 
      MailApp.sendEmail("@gmail.com", "Stock Watchlist alert", message)
      return s2
    }
    else
    {
      ui.alert( stock1name + stock1cmp +  'is less than' +s1 );
      var message = stock1name + stock1cmp +  'is less than' +s1 ;
      MailApp.sendEmail("@gmail.com", "Stock Watchlist alert", message )
      return s1
    }
  }

}
```

This is for single stock. How can I make it more generic and compile all the stock list which pass the condition into single mail. Thanks.

Sen

Comment: Hello @Sen, so what exactly are you trying to achieve? Please provide more details into this matter. How are your stocks grouped? Cheers!

Comment: Hello @ale13, I want to compare the current market price of a stock with my estimated stop loss price. If the current market price goes below my estimated stop loss price I should get email alert. Above code is for single stock but I have list of stock in column A and estimated stop loss price of stock in AL column. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to select *all the values* you will be needing a `for` loop.

#### Snippet

```js
function emailAlert() {

   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Watchlist");
   var stockName = sheet.getRange("A5:FINAL_RANGE").getValues();
   var stockCmp = sheet.getRange("B5:FINAL_RANGE").getValues();
   var s1 = sheet.getRange("AK5:FINAL_RANGE").getValues();
   var s2 = sheet.getRange("AL5:FINAL_RANGE").getValues();

   for (var i = 0; i < stockName.length; i++) {

      if (stockCmp[i][0] < s1[i][0]) {
         if (stockCmp[i][0] < s2[i][0]) {
            ui.alert(stockName[i][0] + stockCmp[i][0] + ' is less than ' + s2[i][0]);
            var message = stockName[i][0] + stockCmp[i][0] + ' is less than ' + s2[i][0];
            MailApp.sendEmail("@gmail.com", "Stock Watchlist Alert", message);
            return s2[i][0];

         } else {
            ui.alert(stockName[i][0] + stockCmp[i][0] + ' is less than ' + s1[i][0]);
            var message = stockName[i][0] + stockCmp[i][0] + ' is less than ' + s1[i][0];
            MailApp.sendEmail("@gmail.com", "Stock Watchlist Alert", message);
            return s1[i][0];
         }
      }
   }

}
```

#### Explanation

The above code loops through all the values from your columns by using a `for` loop and then based on the conditions you set, is sending the email and alerting the user. The range is retrieved by using the `getRange()` method with the `a1Notation` parameter. The `a1Notation` parameter here is represented by the **start** and the **end** of the range in which you have the values you need for the script.

#### Note

The above script is built considering the fact that the `stockName`, `stockCmp`, `s1`, `s2` are all associated, meaning that they all have the same number of values stored in them.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation);
- [JavaScript For Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This what I wanted. Now we are sending mail for each comparison. Is it possible to append the successful events from if loop and send all true events in single mail.

Comment: Hello @Sen, you will just have to send the mail outside the `for` loop with the comparisons wanted and build the message with the comparisons from the loop. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot @ale13